# How could I get the attribute(brand) Url Like example.com/category/brand/name in magento2

Tags: magento2, attributes, url-rewrite

Please give me some Idea,I need some help.

I fetch the brands from those attribute..and get the ids from those attribute.

Ans can send those data on the URL like `example.com/category?brand=7` but I don't want this..

Comment: you can get url like  `example.com/category/brand/7`

Comment: Ya sure freind but i  dont want attribute id.

Comment: do you want brand list using  `example.com/category/brands` ?

Comment: example.com/category/brands/nokia

Comment: is it detail page or grid?

Comment: show on grid page  ...

Comment: if you have nokia as sub-category you will get the url as you want and if you are getting category id in url you can use `url rewrite`

Answer (score 2):

Add your url to URL Rewrite for user friendly url.
if your category `nokia` is a sub-category of brand you can use it.

Comment: Currently when one of the attributes is filtered from my products the url is formed with the #ID number of the value of the attribute.
 
I would like to have the value itself in the URL. I have made a simple image of what I would like to have.

Comment: https://jvdeh29369.i.lithium.com/t5/image/serverpage/image-id/1339i476599B89E7FF831/image-size/original?v=v2&px=-1